# Why table fields are not showing values like first three fields?

Tags: php, html, mysql, database, html-table

Here is some short Code of table.I am using echo in table.

The data is not printing as first three fields.

```
   echo "<table>";
    echo "<tr>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>Date</th>
        <th>Reference</th>
        </tr>" ;
    while ($row = $result->fetch_object())
    {
        echo "<td>" . $row->id . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row->date . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row->ref . "</td>";
            }
    echo "  <tr>
        <th>First Name</th>
        <th>Father Name</th>
        <th>Phone</th>
        </tr>";
    while ($row = $result->fetch_object())
    {
    echo "<td>" . $row->name . "</td>";
                    echo "<td>" . $row->fname . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row->cell . "</td>";
    }
    echo "<tr>
        <th>District</th>
        <th>Address</th>
        <th>Gender</th>
        </tr>";
    while ($row = $result->fetch_object())
    {
    echo "<td>" . $row->district . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row->address . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row->gender . "</td>";
    }
    echo "</table>";
```

Table Output Image

[image: Table Output Image]

Comment: Add **<tr>** tag in all your while loop.

Comment: its not working @Yash

Comment: Show us your expected output vs real output.

Comment: first row consisting heading and second one consisting data

Comment: the first row should consist of heading and second one should be data like first 2 rows in the image i have attached

Comment: You meant one header row following by data row. is it?

Comment: yes u r right @yash

Answer (score 0):

You have missed tr in every dynamic data. change your code as below:

```
echo "<table>";
    echo "<tr>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>Date</th>
        <th>Reference</th>
        </tr>" ;
    while ($row = $result->fetch_object())
    {
        echo "<tr><td>" . $row->id . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row->date . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row->ref . "</td></tr>";
            }
    echo "  <tr>
        <th>First Name</th>
        <th>Father Name</th>
        <th>Phone</th>
        </tr>";
    while ($row = $result->fetch_object())
    {
    echo "<tr><td>" . $row->name . "</td>";
                    echo "<td>" . $row->fname . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row->cell . "</td></tr>";
    }
    echo "<tr>
        <th>District</th>
        <th>Address</th>
        <th>Gender</th>
        </tr>";
    while ($row = $result->fetch_object())
    {
    echo "<tr><td>" . $row->district . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row->address . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row->gender . "</td></tr>";
    }
    echo "</table>";
```

Comment: same as before @B. Desai

Comment: Make sure you have updated code correctly as i have described here

Comment: any other way? @B. Desai